# Change Bootstrap's hover color on nav links?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to change the grey color that pops up when you hover over a nav link, with Bootstrap. Sadly, I can't seem to get it working. (I'm only including this HTML, since stackoverflow won't let me post my jsfiddle link, without it.)

```
    <header role="banner">
    <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="images/logo.png" width="200" alt="Logo Thing main logo"></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header><!-- header role="banner" -->
```

Jsfiddle has all the html/css: https://jsfiddle.net/fzektrm3/2/

I just can't seem to get rid of that ugly grey color, when hovering over the links. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see that Nenad has already solved the problem for you. I would suggest getting to know either Google Chrome's __Developer Tools__ or FireBug. They're great for inspecting elements on the page and looking at what CSS is being applied at that moment in time. Would have been of great use to you for solving this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/fzektrm3/3/

Add this to your **css**, your css must be included after `boostrap` css

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #EF92A5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3

```
<style>
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
         color: white;
         text-decoration: none;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

That comes from default bootstrap CSS

add this code to your CSS file

```
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav > li a:hover{
    background:transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: You both helped immensely. Thank you!